# Is this called Handle or Grip?

Tags: ios, modal

I was wondering what the correct discription for the little handle within an iOS Modal is? The little Handle on the very top of the Modal....Is it a handle? Or a Grip?

[image]

Comment: +1 for a nice clear question

Comment: @PhillipW: +1 for a nice clear comment :D

Comment: @musefan: +1 for a nice clear reply to a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I've just checked their official files here and they call it a `Grabber`

[image]

You can download the files from here:
https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

Comment: Thanks, Grabber sounds perfect :-)